# Android Beta Program: verification failed

Tags: ota-update, nexus-9, 7.0-nougat, android-beta-program

I'm trying to install the Android N preview on my Nexus 9 (volantis). I enrolled for the beta program, and immediately got a notification on the device. After the 1GB download, however, the Android Beta Program updater informs me that validation failed.

I tried several times, also on a different WiFi at work. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that my Nexus 9 was still running the latest Android M preview.

After snagging the latest Android Marshmallow (6.0.1) build for volantis and flashing it manually ([see the instructions here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)), the OTA update came in again and the Android N preview downloaded, validated and installed correctly.

If you don't get offered the OTA update, make sure that you've [enrolled your device for the Android Beta Program here](https://www.google.com/android/beta).